# How to fix the error of geth

Tags: solidity

Q)After installing geth getting an error while attaching.How to fix this error?

```
geth attach
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: no known transport for URL scheme "c"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using 1.8, you need to include the IPC path:

`geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`

See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15746

Answer (score 1):

If you using windows then try:

`geth attach http://localhost:8545`

this will properly work for windows work.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have access to personal and mine objects using localhost ... eth.personal
undefined. Apparently you need to use ipc to get to the lower level objects

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).